# convert list of dict into dict python - pythonic way

Tags: python, python-2.7

input:

```
list = [{'key': '1234', 'value': 100.00}, {'key': '2345', 'value': 200.0}]
```

output:

```
{'1234': 100.00, '2345': 200.0}
```

I now this can be achieved by looping over. Is there any pythonic way to do the same?

Comment: Don't call a list `list`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that a loop would be straightforward.

```
result = {}
for curr in lst:
    result[curr['key']] = result[curr['value']]
```

We can shorten it a bit with a dictionary comprehension. This says the same thing but more compactly

```
result = { curr['key']: curr['value'] for curr in lst }
```

Answer (score 1):

By "pythonic", I take that to mean using things like dict comprehension:

```py
list = [{'key': '1234', 'value': 100.00}, {'key': '2345', 'value': 200.0}]

output = {item["key"]: item["value"] for item in list}

print(output) # {'1234': 100.00, '2345': 200.0}
```

By the way, you might want to rename `list` to something else, because `list` is an internal python function.

Comment: even though it's in a very small scope, probably not great to use `dict` as a variable name in your example either.  ;)

Comment: @Kraigolas yep, just realized and edited!

Answer (score 1):

Just for funsies, a method that involves executing no Python-level code per-item:

```
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [{'key': '1234', 'value': 100.00}, {'key': '2345', 'value': 200.0}]

dct = dict(map(itemgetter('key', 'value'), lst))
```

[The `itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), when passed a `dict` from `lst`, extracts the key and value and returns them as a `tuple`. `map` ensures this is done for each `dict` in `lst`, and the `dict` constructor knows how to turn an iterable of two-`tuple`s into a new `dict`, all without executing a single byte code for any given item (all bytecode involved is fixed overhead to set everything up, then the `map` iterator is run to exhaustion to populate the `dict` without returning control to the byte code eval loop, as long as all keys and values involved are built-ins implemented in C).

Comment: Yeesh, there's so much random stuff I've never used in the operator module.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: Yeah, most of it is pretty useless in most cases. I think I've only ever used five things in it more than once: 1) `operator.truth` (microoptimization; it's faster than `bool` when passing a single positional argument) 2) `operator.index` (a convenient way to take any `int`-like, and losslessly convert to an actual `int`, without lossy coercion like `int()`'s constructor would do) 3-5) `attrgetter`, `itemgetter` and `methodcaller`, all of which are helpful for `map`/`filter` and `sorted` `key` function usage. `concat` and `not_` has come up once or twice, the rest, never.

Comment: But I get so much use out of `index`, `attrgetter`, `itemgetter` and `methodcaller` that they ensure I never forget about that module.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the values of each dict to make the new dict:

```
dict(map(dict.values, lst))
```

---

```
{'1234': 100.0, '2345': 200.0}
```

*Caution the dicts need to be in key/value order like in your example for this to work properly. Which also means this will work fine in Python 3 but you will need to use an `collections.OrderedDict` in python 2.7*

Comment: To be clear, it works fine on Python 3.7+ (as an implementation detail of CPython/PyPy 3.6), not *any* Python 3. The reliance on the `dict`s always being defined `'key'` first, then `'value'` makes this *incredibly* brittle; I'd never rely on it for anything but trivial toy examples ("Uh oh, the data came from JSON, now it only works if the serializer sorted the keys before writing them!").

If you want to use `map` for (perhaps) a tiny bit of efficiency, I'd strongly recommend [using `itemgetter` to guarantee extraction in the correct order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68028012/364696).

Answer (score 0):

It can be writed in one line like this with nested comprehension:

```
data = [{'key': '1234', 'value': 100.00}, {'key': '2345', 'value': 200.0}]
new_dict = {r[0]: r[1] for r in [list(d.values()) for d in data]}
```

Thanks for ShadowRanger it can be simplified to:

```
new_dict = dict(d.values() for d in data)
```

It works only with Python 3.7+ with ordered dicts.

Comment: This only works if the `dict`s in question are always defined in the same, and correct, order (and only on CPython/PyPy 3.6+ or any Python 3.7+, since it implicitly relies on insertion-ordered `dict`s); if `'key'` was inserted second in any `dict`, the result would get it backwards. It's not a safe trick outside of toy examples where the keys and values can be guaranteed to have been set in the proper order.

Comment: Note: If you can make all those assumptions, you can simplify this dramatically; there's no need for all those temporary `list`s you make, nor any explicit indexing. You can just do `new_dict = dict(d.values() for d in data)` (additional assumption: `key` and `value` are the *only* keys in the original `dict`s).

Comment: Thank you. When I try such construction before `new_dict = dict(d.values() for d in data)` I have an error. Now I know it works)